# Pulling a value from a string array using mongodb c#, if it contains substring

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to remove a string from array of strings of a mongodb model, if the string contains substring value

The model is like this

```
{
    "username": "my_user",
    "str_array": [
        "remove_substring_found/rest_of_string",
        "this_string_wont_be_removed"
    ]
}
```

Here is what I tried so far, but it is not working

```
string compare_str = "remove_substring_found";
var filter = Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Eq(s => s.username, "my_user");
var regex = new BsonRegularExpression(string.Format(".*{0}.*", compare_str ), "i");
var filter_update = Builders<string>.Filter.Regex(x => x, regex);
var update = Builders<MyModel>.Update.PullFilter(x => x.str_array, filter_update);
var result = await MyCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik the `PullFilter` only supports complex objects. it doesn't seem to be working for primitive types such as strings. you're supposed to use the `Pull` update operator instead for primitives. but the issue with `Pull` in c# is that it doesn't seem to support regex in a strongly-typed manner. so you need to construct an update definition manually like the following:

```cs
var userFilter = Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Where(i => i.username == "my_user");

UpdateDefinition<MyModel> update = "{ '$pull': { 'str_array': /substring_found/ } }";

await collection.UpdateManyAsync(userFilter, update);
```